# External Media Player suppport for ios application

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayer, ios7.1, carplay

The developer documentation says that the about the new api, that  apps can receive and respond to events sent by external media players using Media Player APIs by using the MPPlayableContentManager class, to control the interactions between the app and the external media player. Here does the reference external media players points to another app's Movie player?

When an app starts, it loads a data source, either from the device or from a server, that contains the available media items and provides this information to the media player. The media player reads and displays this information to the user. 
This can be done with out the new api right? what advantages does the new additions make?

The media player interacts with the app by sending events that the app has registered for. The app responds to an event and changes its behaviour based on the event received.

Answer (score 1):

The `MpPlayableContentManager` class is for use in CarPlay apps - From the Apple class reference

> **Important**: This class is only used for CarPlay. Using it requires a
>   special entitlement issued by Apple. Apps without the correct
>   entitlement will not appear on the CarPlay home screen. See
>   http://www.apple.com/ios/carplay/ for more information.

This class provides an API that allows an app to expose *its* content to the CarPlay interface.  The "Music" app will register its content, the Podcasts app can register podcast content and so on.

Say you create an app that has recordings of the world's greatest sports car engines and you want the driver to be able to pick an engine sound - If Apple grants you a CarPlay entitlement then you app can register its media content and it will appear in the CarPlay interface along with everything else.

The `MPPlayableContentManager` class allows your app to provide your content details and receive commands for playback of the content

This API replaces (and expands) the functionality that was available to car manufacturers who integrated with iDevices via the 30pin/Lighting/USB cable - as now other apps can add their content to the list (if the entitlement is granted)

The existing remote control APIs allow you to receive play/pause/skip events but not to provide a list of content for the user 'browse' on the remote system